# (MPLS) tunneling in OpenFlow

Tags: openflow

We have a network consisting of multiple OpenFlow 1.0 and 1.3 compatible switches, that are interconnected. Each of the switches is connected to one or more switches in a way that there is a route from every switch to every other switch, though not necessarily directly (so the packets might end up having to be passed through multiple switches to reach it's destination).

What I need to do is to get some form of tunneling system, where I can create a flow that passes packets through all these switches to the target machine.

What I know that is possible is to push and pop MPLS labels to the packet. So I figured I might push two labels at the ingress. The outer label identifies the target switch and the inner label identifies the target port. This way I only need flows on each switch to pass packets with matching labels to the target switch first and then to the target port, when it reached the target switch.

The problem here is only that I found no way of matching on MPLS labels. Does anyone know if there is a way to match on these labels? Or is there any other way of doing what I want to do?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can do

`match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=inPort,eth_type=ether.ETH_TYPE_MPLS,mpls_label=m_label)`

that's how you can match mpls labels and give whatever actions you wanna give.